# Scheduling a job based on inserted time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-rest

I have a use case where, I will insert a delivery and it's delivery time in database. Exact at the delivery time the delivery(which is a string) has to be printed to console. Any pointers how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

## `ScheduledExecutorService` with *java.time*

The [Answer by user2880879](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61903190/642706) using `ScheduledExecutorService` would be my chosen approach. But that Answer uses the terrible date-time classes `Calendar` & `Date` which were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

Retrieve delivery moment from database column of a data type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) requires support for [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Check that you got a non-null value.

```
Objects.requireNonNull( odt ) ;  // Throws exception if null.
```

Check that your retrieved moment is in the future.

```
if( ! odt.toInstant().isAfter( now ) ) { … handle error }
```

Tip: You might also want to be sure the future delivery time as at least a certain amount of time in the future, time enough for this code to run and the executor service to execute.

Extract an `Instant` from that `OffsetDateTime`.

```
Instant then = odt.toInstant() ;
```

Calculate elapsed time as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( now , then ) ;
```

Define a task, as a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) or `Callable`.

```
Runnable runnable = () -> { 
    System.out.println( "Delivery made at: " + Instant.now() ) ;
};
```

Somewhere earlier in your app you would have instantiated a `ScheduledExecutorService`, and kept a reference. Using the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) utility class is the usual way to get an executor service.

For this purpose, we likely want a single-threaded service. You can optionally create a service backed by a pool of multiple threads.

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
```

Schedule our task to run after our duration of time elapses.

```
ses.schedule( runnable , duration.toSeconds() , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

Tips:

- Be sure to always gracefully shut down your executor service. Otherwise, the thread(s) backing that service may continue zombie-like long after they are needed, or even after your app has quit.
- Wrap the work done inside your `Runnable` with a try-catch. Any exception bubbling up will *silently* prevent any more tasks scheduled on that executor service from ever executing.

### *Jakarta Concurrency*

If using a [Jakarta](https://jakarta.ee) compliant server supporting the [*Jakarta Concurrency*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/concurrency/) specification, then this work is even easier. That spec relieves you of the chore of starting, managing, and shutting down your executor service.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use JDK's ScheduledExecutorService

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Calendar futureTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    //Here set time when you want to perform logic , display message etc.
    futureTime.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
    Date now = new Date();
    long runafter = now.getTime() - futureTime.getTime().getTime();
    // Within this you can write logic to perform action on that future time
    Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("Hello, execute your logic here");
    //This is one of schedule , will execute your logic defined in Runnable 
    scheduler.schedule(runnable, runafter, MICROSECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume a microservices who has more than one instance responsible for print delivery at delivery time and you want only one instance work at the same time:

**First method**

The answer from @Jalil.Jarjanazy is can help you.code may be like this:

*define job:*

```
public class PrintDeliveryJob implements Job {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        // print job
    }
}
```

*define save delivery method:*

```
public void saveDelivery(String deliveryName, Date deliveryDate) throws Exception {
    saveDeliveryToDataBase(deliveryName, deliveryDate);

    JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob()
        .ofType(PrintDeliveryJob.class)
        .storeDurably().withIdentity(JobKey.jobKey(deliveryName))
        .withDescription("Invoke " + deliveryName + " Job service...").build();
    // you need to calculate the expression，it may be a hard work

    CronExpression cronExpression = null;
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
        .withIdentity(TriggerKey.triggerKey(deliveryName))
        .withDescription(deliveryName + " trigger")
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression).withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()
            .inTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()))
        .forJob(jobDetail)
        .build();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
}


public void saveDeliveryToDataBase(String deliveryName, Date deliveryDate) {
    // save to your data base like mysql、mongodb or other data base
}
```

**Second method**

1、define a job who get data from data base and check if need to print delivery or not.

2、use quartz define a schedule task execute the job one times per second.